# Mac M1 SQL Server SQLSrv OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-silicon, openssl

I just bought a M1 Mac mini running Big Sur 11.6, I've installed PHP 7.3, msodbcsql17, mssql-tools, sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv.

But when I try to connect using sqlsrv, the following error happens [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed]

I've installed openssl@1.1 via brew and my profile contains

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

It seems like PHP is using the correct version, when printing echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT, it says OpenSSL 1.1.1l 24 Aug 2021

I'm not sure what else to try, to make it work?